# clojure data.xml emit-str throws XMLStreamException: Prefix cannot be null

Tags: xml, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am using Clojure's [data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml) library (version 0.0.8, latest stable) to read/write xml files.

I can parse an input stream with `clojure.data.xml/parse` but I cannot find a way to convert the object back to XML.

```
(let [parsed   (clojure.data.xml/parse input)
      back-to-string (clojure.data.xml/emit-str parsed)]
  ...)
```

In this example the `(emit-str parsed)` call throws the following Exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Prefix cannot be null
 at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeAttribute (XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:575)
    clojure.data.xml$write_attributes.invokeStatic (xml.clj:39)
    clojure.data.xml$write_attributes.invoke (xml.clj:35)
    clojure.data.xml$emit_start_tag.invokeStatic (xml.clj:50)
    clojure.data.xml$emit_start_tag.invoke (xml.clj:47)
    clojure.data.xml$emit_event.invokeStatic (xml.clj:67)
    clojure.data.xml$emit_event.invoke (xml.clj:65)
    clojure.data.xml$emit.invokeStatic (xml.clj:379)
    clojure.data.xml$emit.doInvoke (xml.clj:366)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    clojure.data.xml$emit_str.invokeStatic (xml.clj:387)
    clojure.data.xml$emit_str.invoke (xml.clj:383)
```

What is an XML prefix and how do it re-add it to the object?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a small XML sample that reproduces the behavior? What you're doing with the parsed tree could also be causing the issue.

Comment: The exception is thrown even when i do nothing with the tree (just modified example code to make it clear). I will provide a sample soon.

Comment: Could you please show what xml are you trying to parse? Have you tried to parse another xml with the same code?

Comment: An XML prefix is the part of a tag that precedes the :, e.g. the x in  <x:note>blah</x:note> Acceptable prefixes in a document have to be defined in xmlns tags.

Comment: Could be that parser is dropping prefixes - I think I have read about that somewhere.